# Show multiple catch messages in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to display all *catches* instead of only one? In the example below, what if both the username and email are wrong, can I output both instead of just one.

```
try {
    // Code here
}
catch(WrongUsername $e) {
    echo 'Your username is wrong.'
}
catch(WrongEmail $e) {
    echo 'Your email is wrong too.'
}
```

Comment: This is the main reason why I don't use try/catch for validation.

Comment: Eeeeeh You *really* shouldn't throw an exception there. Exceptions are for exceptional cases. Bad user input is not.

Comment: Due to your question and comments that arised I made this another question on programmers.SE that may answer your question or made both of us learn "the correct way", whatever it is: [If the model is validating the data, shouldn't it throw exceptions on bad input?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/201299/if-the-model-is-validating-the-data-shouldnt-it-throw-exceptions-on-bad-input)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably loop thru all the validation rules and cathc all errors.

```
$errors = [];
foreach($rules as $rule){
   try{
      validate($input, $rule);
   }catch(Exception $e){
      $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
   }
}
```

But then I don't see any reason to use try-catch at all.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't really make a lot of sense within PHP - it's dynamically, not fixed typed, and does not support overloading. In your example is 'WrongEmail' the class of the exception or the exception message? Is there a benefit to sub-classing exceptions?

If it's the message property of the exception, then change it to use something more informative...

```
 try {
      ...
      if (!preg_match($pattern, $username)) 
         throw new Exception('Your username is wrong.');
      ...
 } catch ($e) {
      echo $e->message;
 }
```

If you have a good reason for sub-classing your exceptions...

```
 try {
      ...
 } catch ($e) {
    switch (get_class($e)) {
       case 'WrongUsername':
           echo 'Your username is wrong.';
           break;
       case 'WrongEmail':
           echo 'Your email is wrong.'
           break;
       ...
    }
 }
```

But exceptions are part of a flow control structure - when you throw an exception you change the flow of execution. A try{} block will never raise more than one exception. In terms of programming style it's debatable whether you should actually use exceptions at all for this kind of operation.

If you want to check a set of pre-conditions and deal with each failed requirement then don't use this construct.